# Code Highlighting for different languages

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting, codemirror, codehighlighter

I want to create an editor where user can put code in different language by selecting one of the language from dropdown. And code will be highlighted according to that particular language.

What should I use for code highlighting , codemirror looks to be a solution.I have seen many sites where they attribute to codemirror for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll with Github Pages uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) - according to their website, it has support for 300+ languages.  ([Full list here](http://pygments.org/languages/))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of syntax highlighting libraries:

1. [Google code prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)
2. [Prism](https://prismjs.com/)
3. [Hugo (hard to use)](https://gohugo.io/content-management/syntax-highlighting/)
4. [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)
5. [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net)
6. [Chroma (In Golang)](https://github.com/alecthomas/chroma)
7. [Crayon Syntax Highlighter (In PHP)](https://github.com/aramk/crayon-syntax-highlighter)